# How to modify article block in email order confirmation?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I have set up a Magento 2 instance and am trying to modify the email confirmation when ordering. In the admin panel, I found the templates at `Marketing => Email templates`. But it seems the template doesn't include the blocks of the actual order content. Instead I found this:

```html
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}
```

I found this mentioned here in the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-layout-handle.html#email-layout-handle) where it states:

> For example, the sales_email_order_items layout handle is specified in `app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html`:
> `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order_id=$order_id area="frontend"}}`
> The sales_email_order_items handle is an XML file located in app/code/Magento/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml

I have access to the Git project and the admin panel. I can't find the files in the Git repo. Any ideas how I can access and modify this table?

Answer (score 0):

**sales_email_order_items** is the layout handle name. Run the **composer install**, then you can see all Magento module under **vendor/magento** directory. This is your actual layout file:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml

This is your template:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml